# Overwriting Alternate Bytes Pair in C++

Tags: c++, hex

I am trying play sound from one side of the speaker by overwriting alternate bytes pair (2 bytes) with 0s. I checked out in HEX editor, and alternate byte pairs do have repetition.

I made a small program to do the same. However, it is not working. Can you point out what am I doing wrong here?

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file, *fileWrite;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    unsigned long fileLen;
    int n;

    file = fopen("sound.dat", "rb");
    fileWrite = fopen("sound1.dat", "w+");

    // Get the File Length
    //Get file length
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
    n = fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
    printf("%s\n", &buffer);

    int i;

    for(i = 0 ;i < fileLen; i = i + 4)
    {
          buffer[i+2] = '\0';
          buffer[i+3] = '\0';
          // printf("%.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X  \n", (int)buffer[i],(int)buffer[i+1],    (int)buffer[i+2],(int)buffer[i+3]);

    } 

    n = fwrite(buffer, fileLen, 1, fileWrite);

    fclose(file);
    fclose(fileWrite);
}
```

UPDATE: if the hex read is

> 4F D0 4F D0 FF 05 FF 05

i want to make it

> 4F D0 00 00 FF 05 00 00

SOLVED !!!

Can anyone help me out with this: [Audio File: Playing data through one Speaker Only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242366/audio-file-playing-data-through-one-speaker-only)

Comment: You probably want to open `sound1.dat` as binary also (`"wb+"`).  But I doubt that's the source of your problem.

Comment: And what does it output currently?

Comment: Also, your for loop can read off the end of `buffer`.  It checks that `i < fileLen`, but then uses `i+2` and `i+3` as indexes.  Those could potentially be after the end of the buffer.

Comment: Its solved. The issue was opening the file as binary. "wb+".
Also, corrected the loop ends "fileLen - 3"

Answer (score 1):

Your loop bound is off by a few:

```
for(i = 0 ;i < fileLen; i = i + 4)
```

Should be

```
for(i = 0 ;i < fileLen - 3; i = i + 4)
```

Otherwise assigning to `buffer[i + 3]` will overwrite something in memory past the end of buffer. Does this fix the problem?