# Audio File: Playing data through one Speaker Only?

Tags: audio, core-audio

I am working on a simple application which does speaker test. It is intended to first play on the Left Speaker then on Right one (or based on selection). As there is no way of achieving it directly, I am trying to overwrite alternate bytes. I checked out in Hex Editor, and bytes are do repeating in alternate pairs (2 bytes). When worked out with overwriting, it is still playing sound in both speakers.

I am currently using

> 16 bit signed Little Endian

Am I doing something wrong?

These are the available formats I can use while recording the sound:

```
Unsigned 8-bit samples 
Signed 8-bit samples
Unsigned 16-bit little-endian samples
Unsigned 16-bit big-endian samples
Signed 16-bit little-endian samples
Signed 16-bit big-endian samples
```

Comment: What are you using to play the audio?  This will have a big impact on the solution.

Comment: CoolEdit. and other media players are also working same.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to look into using AUPannerUnit, or aupn, which controls the left and right stereo channels. There should be an AUPannerUnits.txt tutorial file that is helpful.

Source: [Apple Audio Unit Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/AudioUnitDevelopmentFundamentals/AudioUnitDevelopmentFundamentals.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I can't make much out of it.
Should I give the sample audio?

Comment: You may want to give more details. When you said you are "making an application to test audio," and used the core audio tag, I thought you were building an Audio Unit. Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish, and how?